# Neural network to generate barcodes

Tags: machine-learning, python, lstm

I am working on a problem regarding barcodes. This is my first time using sequence models practically. Summarizing it:

1. I have 681 32 character, case-insensitive, alphanumeric strings that are supposed to be code-128 barcodes. The strings appear to be random.
2. I have to train a model using this data to produce 'n' unique, 32-character barcodes that follow the given data.
3. Finally, use the generated codes to create Code-128 barcodes.

This is all that I know about the problem.

What I have done so far:

1. Trained a text-generation LSTM model to generate text character-wise on all 681 given strings.
   The model's accuracy on the training data is 98%.
2. Used the trained model to generate 1000 new codes that are unique (tested using pandas.DataFrame.duplicates())

Now, the confusions that I have:

1. Does the 98% accuracy ensure the generated samples to be ~90% similar in pattern to the original codes? Is there any method to test it like some train/test split methods as used in CV, and the 98% metric looks like severe overfitting.
2. How do I convert them to code-128 barcodes. Any links/forums will be very helpful.

Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: This is a completely deterministic problem, you don’t need machine learning for it.

Comment: @Tim I did have a feeling that using ML was an overkill here, but this is what the manager says. Let's assume for a moment that we could only solve it using ML then how well does my approach fit the problem?

Comment: @Hassan maybe spend few minutes on writing the script that translates the barcodes using the deterministic rules that are known, you would have benchmark. The benchmark would have 100% success rate, since the problem is deterministic. Then, after few months of training and experimenting with neural network architectures, you could at least compare how well does your model work as compared to the benchmark.